# Phalcon: display fancy error message instead of standard exceptions

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, innodb, phalcon

using **InnoDb** with `foreignkey` setup in database. In **Phalcon** also setup virtual keys. getting below error *when deleting records* from **phalcon** due to `Foreign Key` setup and also there is still data in child tables.

> My Objective is to display fancy error message to user when this error
>   displayed.

**Showing Error:**

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`invoice`.`invoice`, CONSTRAINT `Invoice.CustomerId` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerId`) REFERENCES `customer` (`Id`))
#0 [internal function]: PDOStatement->execute()
#1 [internal function]: Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->executePrepared(Object(PDOStatement), Array, Array)
#2 [internal function]: Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo->execute('DELETE FROM `in...', Array, Array)
#3 [internal function]: Phalcon\Db\Adapter->delete(Array, '`Id` = ?', Array, Array)
#4 C:\wamp\www\invoice\app\controllers\CustomerController.php(140): Phalcon\Mvc\Model->delete()
#5 [internal function]: CustomerController->deleteAction('3')
#6 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->callActionMethod(Object(CustomerController), 'deleteAction', Array)
#7 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->_dispatch()
#8 [internal function]: Phalcon\Dispatcher->dispatch()
#9 C:\wamp\www\invoice\public\index.php(42): Phalcon\Mvc\Application->handle()
#10 {main}
```

**Fancy Error Message I wanted to display for user:**

> The customer cannot be deleted because other invoices are using it

**This is my model looks like:**

```
<?php
    class Customer extends \Phalcon\Mvc\Model
    {
        public $id;
        public $name;
        public $street;
        public $city;
        public $country;
        public $postalCode;
        public $phone;
        public $mobile;
        public $fax;
        public $email;
        public $web;
        public function initialize()
        {
            $this->setSchema("invoice");
            $this->setSource("customer");
            $this->hasMany(
                'Id',
                'Invoice',
                'Id',
                [
                    'alias' => 'Invoice',
                    'foreignKey' => [
                        'message' => 'The customer cannot be deleted because other invoices are using it',
                    ]
                ]
            );
        }
        public static function find($parameters = null)
        {
            return parent::find($parameters);
        }
        public static function findFirst($parameters = null)
        {
            return parent::findFirst($parameters);
        }
        public function getSource()
        {
            return 'customer';
        }

    }
    ?>
```

Full code is available in [github](https://github.com/syednizamudeen/invoice) in case for reference.

Comment: FYI: models and controllers are created using `php-devtools` i believe there will not be any issues in `relations`

Comment: Catch the exception, then handle it to what suits you. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong relations written.

belongsTo arguments:

- first is attribute(column) in current model, second is related class, third is column in related model

hasMany/hasOne arguments:

- first is column in current model, second is related class, third is column in related model

So in your case it should be for class customer:

```
$this->hasMany(
    'id',
    'Invoice',
    'customerId',
    [
        'alias' => 'Invoices', // it's has many relations so better Invoices alias
        'foreignKey' => [
            'message' => 'The customer cannot be deleted because other invoices are using it',
        ]
    ]
);
```

In Invoice class:

```
$this->belongsTo('customerId', '\Customer', 'id', ['alias' => 'Customer']);
```

Not sure if this alone will fix your issue though.